# Aero Glass Buttons Like Windows Media Player?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, aero, aero-glass

I am making making a program and I want to have a Aero Glass set of controls just like Windows Media Player, I found this: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221200925/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tims/archive/2006/04/18/578637.aspx) but it just draws black. I also found a control that had the media player controls built in right ton the glass but it was no good it didn't want to render right and made different parts of my program not work. Any controls, or ways to extend the Aero glass so I can at least add my own buttons would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

BTW C# only. :)

Comment: This is for a WinForms application?  Or are you working with WPF?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the controls that are used for the buttons in WMP are actually just PNG images overlaid on the extended window border.

Comment: @ Henk & 1kevgrff Windows Form Application is what Im using.

@marrbasta Hmm... Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for here: http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/02/windows-vista-aero-glass-in-net-managed.html

Comment: I've just read the article, it only shows how to change the window glass border, have you found how to change the buttons?

Comment: I just used panels(could use picture boxes) and change the image inside to what I wanted. :)

Comment: Hmm, why did you mark an answer that didn't answer the question?